# Parsing special character pattern using sscanf in C

Tags: regex, parsing, controls, scanf

I am working on a command parser that is supposed to accept a command line terminating with \r\n and extract its parameters

The command line structure is as follows:

all the parameters inside () are mandatory and the arguments inside [] are optional,and *spc* 
stands for blank-space or space. and \t stands for tab

AP is and decimal integer between 1...4
RT,WL are a decimal unsigned integer numbers
= is equal symbol
% is percentage symbol
Followings is an acceptable command structure

[*spc*] MYCMD [*spc*] (\t) [*spc*] (AP) [*spc*] (:) (WL)(=)(RT)*spc**spc*(\n)

As an example follwoing commands sre correct: (The whole command is case insensitive)

*MYCMD    \t 1 :  540 = 21% \r\n*

*MYCMD    \t 2 :  712= 25  % \r\n*

*MYCMD\t 3 :  200 =17%\r\n*

and ...

Following commands are incorrect:

**MYCMD    \t 5:  540 = 21% \r\n   ---> 5 is not in range 1..4**

**MYCMD    \t 2 :  712 25% \r\n    ---> There is no equal symbol**

**MYCMD 3 200 =17\r\n   --->there is no : between 3 and 200, no percentage symbol**

**MYCMD 3 100 =1   ,,.\n ----> there are extra symbols after 1 and \r does not exist**

**MYCMD 2: 130 =17.1\r\n ----> the sscanf parser must not translate 17.1 float to integer 7**

I have implemented sscanf control format but it does not parse correctly!

```
int n_parsed=sscanf(cmd_str,"%*sMYCMD[*^\t]%*s%[1234]:%u%*s%[=]%u\r\n",&int_ap,&uint_wl,&uint_rt);
```

But this does not work for the correct commands (n_parsed never gets 3).

Any hint or comments on fixing the parsing issue will be appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be done solely with `sscanf()`.

A key problem is that `" "` as well as `"\r"` as well as `"\n"` in the format string (aside from inside `"[ ]"`) will *optionally* scan *any* number 0+ white-spaces and OP has very specific requirements.  Optional spaces `' '`, but not other white-spaces, is difficult to do in `sscanf()`.

Another problem is the `%d` et al, consume optionally leading whitespace and we need to prevent that or let it go.

There is a discrepancy between the format and the examples in the location of the "%".  I assume the example is correct.

There is a discrepancy between the format and the examples in the end-of-line `\r\n` versus `\n`.  I assume any trailing whitespace before a final \r\n.

There is a discrepancy between the format and the examples in that spaces are allowed before the numbers.  I assume spaces are OK.

The more I look at it I see lots of discrepancies between the stated format and the correct examples.  I'll go for whatever is easiest to pass the examples in those cases.

```
int sep[4] = { 0 };
int int_ap;
unsigned uint_wl, uint_rt;

// [spc] MYCMD [spc] (\t) [spc] (AP) [spc] (:) (WL)(RT)(=)spcspc(\n)
const char *format = " MYCMD%n %n%1d :%u =%u%n %n";

int n_parsed = sscanf(cmd_str, format, 
    &sep[0], &sep[1], &int_ap, &uint_wl, &uint_rt, &sep[2], &sep[3]);

if (sep[3] == 0) DidNotReadEnd();  
if ((int_ap < 1) || (int_ap > 4)) RangeError();
unsigned TabCount = 0;
int n;
for (n = sep[0]; n < sep[1]; n++) {
  if (cmd_str[n] == '\t')  TabCount++;
}
if (TabCount != 1) WrongTabCount;
for (n = sep[2]; n < sep[3]; n++) {
  if (cmd_str[n] != ' ') break;
}
if (strcmp(&cmd_str[n], "\r\n") != 0) EOLError();
```

Note: int_ap could be scanned with `%1[1-4]` into a string and than converted to an `int`.

I fully expect a claim that this can all be done with only a `sscanf()` format.  I am confident such and approach can be broken.